# iTextSharp PDF vindo em branco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itextsharp

Boa Tarde pessoal, tenho o seguinte código:

```
 public void GerarPDF(long id)
    {
        string HTMLemString = RenderizaHtmlComoString("~/Views/item/item.cshtml", id);
        var regex = new Regex("(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)",
            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        HTMLemString = regex.Replace(HTMLemString, "");
        string CSSdocumento = CSSemString();
        Byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    var HTMLconversão = '@' + HTMLemString;
                    var CSSconversão = '@' + CSSdocumento;

                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CSSconversão)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLconversão)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        new XmlController().SalvarPDF(bytes);

    }
```

O código que gera o PDF, e abaixo onde eu recebo o PDF e o utilizo:

```
 byte[] PDF = PDFparaAnexo;
 List<MemoryStream> anexos = new List<MemoryStream>();
        anexos.Add(new MemoryStream(PDF));
```

E abaixo onde junto o arquivo que se encontra em uma memorystream, com o seu nome:

```
int i = 0;
            foreach (Stream anx in pAnex)
            {
                try
                {
                    Attachment attached = new Attachment(anx, pFileName[i]);
                    mm.Attachments.Add(attached);
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            }
```

Só que o arquivo esta indo em formato PDF mas esta em branco, alguém saberia o por que?

Comment: Já achou o problema? Já testou esse regex pra ver se não está removendo todo texto?